# Change a Variable in PHP if its contained in a Text File

Tags: php, filter, fopen

What Im Trying to do here is set up some sort of filter.

I have no source code at the moment, but I can type it up quick after i find out how to do this.

So Say I have

```
$Variable1 = "The Brown Fox Jumps";
```

I want a If statement where

```
IF $Variable1 contains a word from a .txt file (filter.txt) Then $Variable1 = "Filtered"
```

so if the text file contained

```
Hey
Hi
Jump
Brown
```

It would change the whole thing to filtered. I Dont know how I would write that, so a little help typing it would be nice :)

Thanks Guys

Comment: Your description is not complete. What if `$Variable1` holds `Hey Hi` or `Hi Hey` or `Hi Hey foo`?

Comment: If Variable 1 Holds Any word contained inside the .txt file.

Comment: You probably don't want to use stripos because that will match partial words. Bad word 'an' will match 'pan', 'can','ants', etc... Maybe that's what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you file is delimeted by newlines:

```
$file = file_get_contents('filter.txt');
$bad_words = explode(PHP_EOL, $file); // If PHP_EOL doesn't work there are other EOL characters you can try.
$variable1 = "This is some string."
$compare = explode(' ', $variable1);
if(count(array_intersect($bad_words, $compare)) > 0){
  $variable1 = 'Filtered';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

And what is it you don't understand?

I would say, simplest way:

1) read text file: `$str = file_get_contents('filter.txt');`

2) explode content of text file into array :
   (first parameter is the delimiter character, change that if necessary)

```
$badwords = explode(" ",$str);
```

3) if your `$variable` matches any of the words in your newly created array, change it into 'filtered':

```
foreach($badwords as $badword) {
   if(stristr($badword,$variable) {
       $variable = 'filtered';
       break;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Not sure how big the text file is, but when I did a speed test a while back on foreach() vs. stripos, stripos was much faster.

Comment: You mean stristr vs stripos? Because you most certainly need a foreach because he wants to check "1 or more" words from the text file against the `$variable`, not the entire contents of the text file.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your code when I glanced at it.  My apologies!

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't change the variable name per se as much as much as assign a new variable to it.

```
// if you want to search by ONE word
$file = file_get_contents(your_text_file_here);

if(stripos($file, $variable1)){
// there was a match
  $variable1 = "Filtered";
}



// if you want to search your document for MULTIPLE words
$file = file_get_contents(your_text_file_here);

foreach(explode(' ', $file) as $word) {
  if(stripos($word, $variable1)){
  // there was a match
    $variable1 = "Filtered";
  }
}
```

I'm not quite sure if this helps, but stripos is a function that takes a string and case-insensitively determines if there is a match.

If you type up some code, then I think I can help you further.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your code:

```
$filters = file('filter.txt');
foreach( $filters AS $word ) {
  if( stripos( $Variable1, $word ) !== null ) {
     $Variable1 = 'filtered';
     break;
   }
}
```